# Как удалить защищенный файл

Tags: docker, magento

Софт:

- Windows 10
- pHpStorm 9.0
- Docker

Поднял локально Magento 2 на Docker/ Столкнулся с проблемой, во время выполнения

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

в Windows PowerShell, получаю exception:

`[Exception]
 Missing write permissions to the following paths:
 /www/public_html/pub/static/frontend/EVThemes/MyTheme/en_US/images/loader-1.gif`

Удалить данный файл также не получается с директории images. Unlocker не помогает.

На данный момент единственное решение, хоть и не очень удобное:

- выйти из Docker (закрыть);
- удалить данный файл;
- снова запустить Docker;
- поднять проект;
- выполнить `setup:upgrade`

Подскажите, как избежать этого? Как удалить такие файлы?

P.S.: это может быть не только файл картинки, иногда и JS файлы встречаются, например `require.js`

Comment: покажите Dockerfile и как вы запускаете контейнер

Comment: контейнер запускаю в PowerShell `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос и не забудьте про Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml